# Can you have a panel fixed to the right in Bootstrap 3?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, panel

I have a panel that floats right within a container.  When my data-spy affix executes, the side-panel gains the `position: fixed` property which removes the `float: right`.  The panel becomes fixed at the correct height, but becomes fixed at the left in the container not the right in the container.  I cannot simply state a fixed value for the left property because I am using a container fixed to `1200px`, not `container-fluid` and the left offset changes whenever the user resizes their screen.

How can I set the panel mimic float-right while affixed near the top of the view?

```
<div id="navbarContainer" class="affix-top clearfix" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="70">
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" role="navigation" id="topnavbar">
    </div>
</div>

// code removed

<div class="container">
 <div id="right_panel" class="panel right-panel pull-right">
     <div class="panel-head">
         Related Information
     </div>
  <div class="panel-body">A Basic Panel</div>
</div>
```

css

```
.rightpanelAffix{
    position:fixed;
    top:101px;
}
```

js

```
$("#navbarContainer").on("affixed.bs.affix", function () {
    $("#body").addClass("bodyAffixPadding");
    $("#right_panel").addClass("rightpanelAffix");
});

$("#navbarContainer").on("affixed-top.bs.affix", function () {
    $("#body").removeClass("bodyAffixPadding");
    $("#right_panel").removeClass("rightpanelAffix");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Show us some code. and may be you want to ask that you can't adjust your container size.  Let me know if this helps.
Check this out

```
 <div class="container">
                   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-6"></div></div></div>
```

Comment: The panel is sitting outside of a row.  When we go to small size screens, the panel will open from a button rather than always available.

Comment: then Add this <div class="col-lg-1 col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-8>

Comment: Approve my Answer please if you think it would help you. :)